# Why does docker-compose issue a "No such file or directory" when the file is there?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am testing a bare metal recovery of my server which basically starts a set of docker container with my services. I recovered from a backup `/etc/docker`, where I keep all the configuration and persistent volumes.

I then tried to start one of the containers:

```
root@srv-backup:/etc/docker# docker-compose --verbose -f /etc/docker/docker-compose.d/20-registry.yaml up
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: /etc/docker/docker-compose.d/20-registry.yaml
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: .IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/docker/docker-compose.d/20-registry.yaml'
```

The file is however there:

```
root@srv-backup:/# ll /etc/docker/docker-compose.d/20-registry.yaml
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 root root 842 Jan 24 15:19 /etc/docker/docker-compose.d/20-registry.yaml*

root@srv-backup:/# cat /etc/docker/docker-compose.d/20-registry.yaml
services:
  registry:
    container_name: registry
    image: registry
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.registry.rule=Host(`registry.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.registry.entryPoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.registry.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.registry.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.middlewares.lan.ipwhitelist.sourcerange=192.168.10.0/24, 192.168.20.0/24
      - traefik.http.routers.registry.middlewares=lan
      - traefik.enable=true
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /etc/docker/container-data/registry:/var/lib/registry
version: '3'

root@srv-backup:/# file /etc/docker/container-data/registry
/etc/docker/container-data/registry: directory
```

I tried all kind of incantations with relative and full paths - the issue is the same.

I was wondering whether the docker daemon has access to the file, but it also runs as `root`:

```
root@srv-backup:/# ps -ef | grep docker
root      2048     1  0 10:58 ?        00:00:08 dockerd -G docker --exec-root=/var/snap/docker/423/run/docker --data-root=/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker --pidfile=/var/snap/docker/423/run/docker.pid --config-file=/var/snap/docker/423/config/daemon.json
root      2200  2048  0 10:58 ?        00:00:07 containerd --config /var/snap/docker/423/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml --log-level error
```

I am quite at loss why it does not work (the docker file works correctly on the server I am trying to replicate in this DRP exercise)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a workaround (this is not exactly an answer to the problem, but allows to go forward).

1. I uninstalled the `docker` snap installation: `snap remove docker`
2. I installed `docker` from the repositories: `apt install docker.io`
3. I [installed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-18-04) `docker-compose`:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Now the command I used to start the example container works.

There must be something special with the snap version of `docker`.

Comment: My guess would be some limitation of snap. It restricts file access quite heavily.

Answer (score 2):

This actually helped me

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir docker-compose && ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: This forces a reinstallation of docker-compose, but will it solve the issue of the question?

Answer (score 2):

It could also be as simple as it was by me:
Just start docker.

The error message was a bit irritating.

Comment: Irritating indeed. Such a misleading and unhelpful error :(

Answer (score 1):

the problem could be related to the python version
docker-compose 1.27.x runs for me with Python 3.6.x
for >= 1.28 , one would need 3.7.x
docker-compose >= 1.27 dropped support for Python 2.7

I am not aware of lower version numbers

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same error, but in my case it could not find the `Dockerfile`. And it turns out that the **file path I had specified was not valid from the context path** I had provided. For example, I had:

```
/myproject
  /myapp
  /docker
    /myapp.Dockerfile
    /docker-compose.yaml
```

and in `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  myapp:
  build:
    context: ..
    dockerfile: myapp.Dockerfile
```

and then I was running with:

```
cd /myproject/docker
docker compose up -d
```

It would complain the `myapp.Dockerfile` could not be found, and it turns out it was right.
The context was specified as the parent folder (`..`) so `dockerfile` property should be `docker/myapp.Dockerfile`.